# Should "axis" be italicized in LaTeX captions?

Tags: captions

This seems more a grammar question than a LaTeX but here it is. It would be stranger if I posted it in the English stack site.

What is the correct way to say see x axis:

```
    (1) see $x-axis$
    (2) see $x$-axis
```

In (1) x-axis appears italicized, in (2) it does not. I am following the general rule that variables should be italicized.

Comment: clearly the second one! The first means and looks like »x minus a times x times i times s« while the second means and looks like »x-axis«. If you want that in italics: `\textit{$x$-axis}`

Comment: The variable should be italicized, but “axis” is a plain English word (well, it's Latin, actually), so it should be typeset in the current font. The “most correct” way is `$x$\nobreakdash-axis` (after loading `amsmath`).

Comment: The Latin word itself is derived from the Greek word ἄξων, that we find in ‘axonometric’.

Answer (score 4):

The first solution is wrong as this means: "x minus a times x times i times s". As you are following the rule that variables should be italicized, you should just check if "axis" is a variable. It is not; it's not varying and it is a full English word.

The second one is much better. If you would like to get everything italicized, you should write `\textit{$x$-axis}` or `$x$-\emph{axis}` or alike.

It is best practise to prevent a line break for this hyphen. Therefore, you should write `$x$\nobreakdash-axis` (`{amsmath}`) or `$x$\hbox{-}axis` or `$x$"~Achse` (`[ngerman]{babel}`)